# AWS @SqsListener not working with spring cloud (using springboot 3)

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

Currently, we have an SQS client configured using an IAM Role that is picked up on the cluster. However, migrating over to Springboot 3 the @SqsListener is no longer consuming the messages.

NOTE: Same code, works on Springboot 2, but not on Springboot 3 is there something else that needs to be configured or am I missing something?

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.awspring.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs/3.1.1 Use this.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Cloud AWS 2.x is only compatible with Spring Boot 2.x, for Spring Boot 3.x, Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 is necessary.

See compatibility [here](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions).

The 3.0 RC version has just been released, feel free to try it out and provide feedback!

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on the sample code to work within a Spring Boot 3 context? I have thus far been unable to get the listener to work in a clean Spring Boot 3 project. Would like to know which io.awspring dependencies are need and if any com.amazonaws libs are required too.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in a bit more details what you need in a new question or in the Spring Cloud AWS Github repository? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**SQS message listener with spring boot 3**

Add following in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Use BOM provided by spring for version managament -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

- Use io.awspring.cloud.sqs.annotation.SqsListener to listen the messages instead of io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener
- If "Visibility timeout" of SQS is less than listener's processing time then message needs to be deleted explicitly from the queue, otherwise same message could be processed multiple times.

Working example: https://github.com/raovikash/sqs-listener-spring-boot3

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 3.0x requires Spring Cloud AWS 3.0x and AWS Java SDK 2.x

Visit this [link](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions) for info

In order to create a Consumer in Spring Boot 3.0, you need to use `@EnableScheduling` Bean in your main application. Then you need to use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)` above the *receive* method. **@Scheduled** bean replaces the **@SqsListener** here. You can visit this [link](https://javatodev.com/how-to-use-amazon-sqs-with-spring-boot/) for more info.

Comment: A mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer on Stack Overflow. Please at least summarize what's behind the link.

Comment: Thanks; this does indeed work but feels bit rudimentary. The @SqsListener annotation driven operation from Spring Boot 2.x would be my preferred approach. Looking for a way to get this to work in Spring Boot 3.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `@SqsListener` annotation to work, the dependency [spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.awspring.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure) is required - this autowires the containers etc. needed for the annotation to function. [You can see the extra stuff it autowires here](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/autoconfigure/sqs/SqsAutoConfiguration.java).

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableSqs
```

add this annotation in the class where you are using `@SqsListener` in spring boot 3

Comment: I cant find @EnableSqs annotation